# How to create a Non US App profile when creating app through intuit developer IPP

Tags: rest, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When we specify a domain with a country suffix such as ***.au*** (domain.com.au) the input when creating the app profile (MyApps/Create New App) is rejected. However if we specify a domain with just ***.com*** as the suffix then it works fine. Is there a way around this? like a workaround? Does the app profile need to be accurate from the start or can we change it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App profile doesn't need to be accurate from start. In the development env, you can use dummy URL(like localhost.com).